# Enable remote VNC for kvm+qemu

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, vnc

I'm using `kvm+qemu` on Ubuntu 14.04 Server.

I need to enable VNC for remote hosts, so I edited `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` and uncommented `vnc_listen = "0.0.0.0"` there.

My problem, is that I don't know how to reload this configuration file without restarting all the hosts. Already tried:

`service libvirt-bin reload`
`reload libvirt-bin`
and `killall -HUP libvirtd` without success. Is there a way to reload this configuration file? Or do I need to restart all the guests?

Answer (score 1):

Do not do it in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`, but rather do it in the definition file for the guest itself, for example in `/etc/libvirt/qemu/serv64_dev.xml`. here is an example of the relevant section:

```
<graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0'>
  <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
</graphics>
<video>
  <model type='vmvga' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
</video>
```

Use `virsh edit domain name` to edit, example `virsh edit serv64_dev` (from any directory), as it does some additional checks upon exit.

The default editor used by `virsh edit` is as defined by the $EDITOR environment variable, or VI if it does not exist. add `export EDITOR="/bin/nano"` to your `~/.bashrc` file to set, for example, nano as your default editor.

Comment: Done, but still I can't connect (nor telnet to port 5904, which is the one assigned to that VM)

Comment: I would have expected it to be on port 5900, unless there are already 4 others that started before it.

Comment: It's the fourth VM, `virsh vncdisplay MyVM` reports `:4`.
In any case, all ports from 5900 to 5904 are unaccessible through telnet...

Comment: And you are attempting to connect to the host IP address port 5904, right? Then, I am out of ideas, as I have only ever made my VM's with VNC support to start with. If you think it will help, I can post my entire .xml file.

Comment: Yes, host IP address. Don't worry posting the entire xml, I'll try changing `qemu.conf` and see if that helps.

Comment: O.K., Please post back how you make out. By the way, I have never edited `qemu.conf`

Comment: Do you have a firewall (iptables or ufw or ?) blocking access to those ports?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the port in Ubuntu's firewall as well.

```bsh
root@ubuntu:~# ufw allow 5901
Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)
```